# Passing String values with Position from RVAdapter to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am trying to pass Button click number value with position of recyclerview adapter to activity. I failed to do it with both Interface. For eg; I click first row of Button to get "2" & I Log Button getNumber() is "2". It is okay. But when I click second row & Log is "2", actually second row Button number is "1". I don't know how to get value with position.

Here interface,

```
public interface OnItemClick {
    void onClick(String value, int position);
}
```

adapter,

```
private OnItemClick mCallback;

    public SubMenuRVAdapter(Context context, List<SubMenu> subMenuList, OnItemClick mCallback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.subMenuList = subMenuList;
        this.mCallback = mCallback;
    }

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnClickListener() { // onBindViewHolder
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String num = holder.button.getNumber();
            mCallback.onClick(num, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
```

Activity,

```
public class SubMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClick {    

     SubMenuRVAdapter adapter = new SubMenuRVAdapter(SubMenuActivity.this, subMenus, SubMenuActivity.this);
     recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);

     @Override
     public void onClick(String value, int position) {
         num = value;
     }
}
```

Comment: how are you assigning value to button? please post full adapter code.

Comment: call `setOnClickListener` inside your custom `ViewHolder` constructor and use `getAdapterPosition()` in order to get your real data (`number` in your case)

Comment: @Mohammed Farhan what does u mean?

Comment: @pskink yes inside ViewHolder, but how to check positon at onClick() of activity?

Comment: as i said call `setOnClickListener(this)` inside your custom `ViewHolder` constructor, did you do that?

Comment: Not yet button.setOnClickListener(this), after call setOnClickListener, what i need to do?